# Getting Text out of URL into String Android

Tags: android, string, text, get

I want to get Text out of an URL into my Android String.

Website:

```
<html>
<body>
Text I don't want to get.
<div id="editorText" class="answer" itemprop="text">Text I want to get</div>
</body>
Text I don't want to get.
<html>
```

Android:
I want that the result is like that:

```
String text = "Text I want to get";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jsoup library to parse html string for more details check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all the content and parse (maybe 'substring') the content to get what you want based on pattern's. In this case it's somethins like:

```
String urlContent = ...//getContent from URL
String beginPattern = "itemprop='text'>";
String endPattern = "</div>";
int begin = urlContent.indexOf(beginPattern)+beginPattern.length();
int end = urlContent.indexOf(endPattern);
String contentNeeded = urlContent.substring(begin, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsoup library as mentioned by Maulik and write this code

```
            try {
                Document doc= Jsoup.connect("url of the page").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("MyTag", e.getMessage());
            }
            Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag("body");
            for(Element ele: elements){
                String text = ele.ownText();
                // Now here you need to add some logic
            }
```

Comment: Which Jsoup Version are you using? Does it work on Android? can I add this code everywhere?

Comment: jsoup-1.7.3 and yes it is working on Android as i am using it in Android application. Beside this as it is a plain Java code it will also work fine on Java too.